# How to narrow down the process listing output below UNIX/LINUX

Tags: linux, unix

```
FROM:
 noaccess  7491  6817   0   Jul 19 ?         281:19 /usr/java/bin/java -     
 server -Xmx128m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
 oracle  1715 11577   0   Nov 23 ?          32:33                                                      
 /appl/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/bin/java -server -Xmx256M - 
 XX:MaxPermSize=
 virtuo 21844 21814   0 17:27:27 pts/3       0:00 grep java

 TO:
  noaccess  7491  6817   0   Jul 19 ?         281:19 /usr/java/bin/java - 
  server -Xmx128m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
  oracle  1715 11577   0   Nov 23 ?          32:33  
  /appl/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/jdk/bin/java -server -Xmx256M -
  XX:MaxPermSize=
```

I need to remove virtuo 21844 21814   0 17:27:27 pts/3       0:00 grep java line

I am really new to UNIX/LINUX command.

Comment: How do you get this list of processes?

Comment: its my assignment. try out to enter unix/linux course @Michael

Comment: You did not understand my question. I meant to say that the answer to your depends on the command. Fore example, if you run something like `ps -ef | grep something` the simplest way to remove the `grep` from the output would be `ps -ef | grep something | grep -v grep` .  The answer would differ for another original command

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your FROM output was generated from an 'X' command, so:

`X | sed '$d'`

That will remove the last line of the output. To remove a specific line, you could use something like:

`X | sed '/regex/d'`

That will remove every line that has a match on the passed regex.